# how javascript array value pass in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
var exp_array_string = [];

exp_array_string[0] = "";
exp_array_string[1] = "maincode=P0010250&tablename=prod_fert_st_mn&prod_code=FR00001&frequency=m&highlimit=35&model=f";

exp_array_string[2] =
    "maincode=P0021000&tablename=prod_auto_st_mn&prod_code=AU00001&frequency=m&highlimit=35&model=a";
exp_array_string[3] =

maincode = P0051000&tablename=prod_oil_st_mn_ts&prod_code=OIL0030&frequency=m&highlimit=35&model=o


for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

    var exp_datastring = exp_array_string[i];

    <?php
        $a = "<script language='javascript'>document.write(exp_datastring);</script>";
        <td valign="bottom" align="right" height="20" id='11'>
    <?php $export_xls = "/index.php?$a";  ?> 
    <a href = "<?php echo $export_xls;?>" >
    <img src = "/sites/themes/download_excell_btn_dshbrd.jpg" alt = "" border = "0" / ></a>
    </td >
```

i wan to show in export like index.php ?`maincode=P0010250&tablename=prod_fert_st_mn&prod_code=FR00001&frequency=m&highli`

but they showing in index.php?document.write(exp_datastring) 
what can i do now

Comment: if you want to pass values to `php` you are maybe refering to `ajax` or `xhr`

Comment: Your question is not clear at all to me, so a first guess: `$export_xls = "/index.php?$exp_datastring";`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, The reason is that
PHP is Server side and Javascript is client side so when PHP executes the javascript not and vice versa.

It's better to use ajax for your purpose. Currently you are doing is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, PHP is server side : means already executed when JS is executed on client, you may do something like this JS only

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
var exp_array_string=[
  "maincode=P0010250&tablename=prod_fert_st_mn&prod_code=FR00001&frequency=m&highlimit=35&model=f",
  "maincode=P0021000&tablename=prod_auto_st_mn&prod_code=AU00001&frequency=m&highlimit=35&model=a",
  "maincode=P0051000&tablename=prod_oil_st_mn_ts&prod_code=OIL0030&frequency=m&highlimit=35&model=o"
];

for(var i in exp_array_string){
 document.write('<td valign="bottom" align="right" height="20" id="11">');
 document.write('<a href="/index.php?'+exp_array_string[i]+'">');
 document.write('<img src="/sites/themes/download_excell_btn_dshbrd.jpg" alt="export" border="0" /></a></td>');
}
</script>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can store document.write value in php?iam using in php when i click export url like $export_xls then open index.php page

Comment: by gathering your informations on server side with php, or by sending xhr request on the server. No way to assign JS variables to PHP on client side (what you are trying)